# Possible to make a one account per person website?

Tags: html, css, web, user-accounts

Is it possible to make a website with only one account per person?

Any suggestion is good.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because my english is not the best, but... Could you explain a little bit more what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Nobita: It sounds like he's looking for a way to uniquely identify a visitor and prevent people from creating multiple accounts.  To this, I can only tell him "good luck."

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want people to go generating 100 accounts a minute, you'll need something like captcha, which is very easy to add on to your website.

You can do other things, like associate each account with an email address, and make the user verify that that email actually exists by sending a link out to that email address so that when they click on it, it verifies the connection.

To associate exactly one account per person, you are going to need to use some sort of official identity, and usually for smaller websites that doesn't make sense. By official identity I mean verify their credit card or government identification (social security?), but then you run into a lot of problems because people won't want to do this, and it is going to cost money to make sure that these identities are real. Also, if you really need something like this, you're going to have to beef up the security of your website.

Comment: And in some countries you're not allowed to ask for people's social security number. I know it isn't allowed here for starters (the Netherlands).

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that this doesn't really make sense for expanding internationally. That last paragraph was really "you could do this, but it absolutely never makes sense to".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to require a user to put in a verification number which you send to them via SMS, and ensure the phone number they enter is unique, phones/simcards are relatively cheap these days, but most people wouldn't go through the effort of spending $5 on a new simcard to get a duplicate account on your site.

(and if they would, sell accounts for $3 and undercut the cost of a sim ;)

Comment: Tools like https://www.twilio.com/sms and AWS SNS will enable you to do this quite cheaply.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for identifying information for example credit card data that you can verify and allow registrations only with this identifying information. Of course credit card data can be stolen, so you cannot be 100% sure about anything in internet or in world generally.

Comment: In most situations, this "fix" would be worse than the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, people will still try to buck the system. If you use Email, then people can have multiple free emails, if you block free emails, lots of people dont have any other emails so you block them. If you use IP you block anyone with a shared IP such as ISPs who enforce proxy servers for their clients.

Unless you start asking for social security numbers or NI or whatever your country has, and you start alienating people as a rule because they would consider that irrelevant personal information.

You just have to hope people treat your site fairly, and know some wont.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution these days is to only create user accounts via federation of identity from a much stricter service provider.  For example, verify your users **via a facebook account** using oauth.  I believe **facebook is pretty good at detecting shills/spammers** and you can harness their resources in your service too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options, neither of which will solve the whole problem:

1. Log the IP address and prevent multiple logins from one IP.  Not great, as this will probably backfire if college kids use your site and the dorm uses shared IPs.
2. Log the MAC address and prevent multiple logins from one MAC.  Better, but it will prevent multiple people from the same household from using your site, and most houses have more than one computer/mobile device.

You could always combine the two options, but again with multiple mobile devices it's possible to circumnavigate that.

Answer (score -1):

you could make a code that only lets 1 account be made per computer used. you have to be able to get the computers IP address and block it from making more than 1 account.

Comment: There are a) many legitimate reasons multiple people would be using one IP address (roommates, family members, a dormitory, a school, a business) and b) many ways to get new IP addresses (Tor, turning off your cable modem for a while, proxies).